# How to invert Expand

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

How do I invert Expand?
I have

```
lis={1 + x^2, 2 + 2 x^2 + x^4, 5 + 8 x^2 + 8 x^4 + 4 x^6 + x^8}
```

and want to get

```
{1 + x^2, 1 + (1 + x^2)^2, 1 + (1 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2}
```

Comment: `HornerForm /@ lis` gets close to it but not really

Comment: Yes, I already tried HornerForm.

Comment: Have you tried nesting `Decompose`?

Comment: I am trying but to no avail

Comment: This gets you close to what you want:  `(lis /. x -> Sqrt[y^2 - 1] // Expand) //. y -> Sqrt[x^2 + 1]`.  Maybe throwing in `HornerForm` somewhere in the middle of that will get you what you want.

Comment: This is close but it still takes some tricks. How come the inversion of Expand[Table[Nest[1 + #^2 &, x, i], {i, 3}]] is so hard? Is this equal to the factoring problem?